# Sculpting does not give a visible change in my model

Tags: sculpting

So im new to blender and im following this tutorial from youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OTX3ZdYvEA

When i try to use the sculpture mode to dent in the side, it just doesnt do anything. Ive been shoving my mouse all over the  model and sometimes i get a random dent but nothing that gives me the impression that it is reacting to what i'm doing. What am i missing? Did i forget some layer or something?

Comment: by default sculpting will use the topology of your mesh, if it's a low-poly mesh you won't see anything, unless you activate the Dyntopo option in the N panel, in that case make also sure that the Detail Size is low enough

Comment: is this mesh another layer like "Subdivision" (the wrench icon) or is just the model itself?
Edit: It's my Taurus ring. Ill try the Dyntopo option to see wether i get a different reaction

Comment: Dyntopo will affect the mesh itself, it will add vertices on the part you are sculpting, and the size of the tris that are create will depend on the Detail Size value. If you don't want to affect the mesh itself, you can use the Multiresolution modifier instead. But you can also save your low-poly version, sculpt with Dyntopo, then bake the normals of this second version and use it on the low-poly version.